# rest api flutter get method works while post doesnt

Tags: android, django, flutter, rest, dart

ihave this error from server response [image: server error]

this is the models and api

u can find full source code here https://github.com/alihassan75/project

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final task = taskFromJson(jsonString);
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

//List<Task> taskFromJson(String str) => List<Task>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Task.fromJson(x)));

//String taskToJson(List<Task> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Project {
 Project({
this.id,
required this.project_name,
this.created_at,
// required this.start_date,
//required this.end_date,
required this.user,
 });

  int? id;
 final String? project_name;
  DateTime? created_at;
 // final DateTime? start_date;
  //final DateTime? end_date;
  int user;

 factory Project.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Project(
   id: json["id"],
   project_name: json["project_name"],
   created_at: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
   // start_date: DateTime.parse(json["start_date"]),
   //end_date: DateTime.parse(json["end_date"]),
   user: json["user"],
 );

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
   "id": id,
   "project_name": project_name,
   "created_at": created_at?.toIso8601String(),
   // "start_date": start_date?.toIso8601String(),
    //"end_date": end_date?.toIso8601String(),
   "user": user,
 };
}
class ProjectProvider with ChangeNotifier{
 ProjectProvider(){
   this.fetchProject();
 }


 List<Project> _project = [];
 List<Project> get project {
   return [..._project];
 }

   void addProject(Project project) async {
   final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/project/api'),
       headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, body: json.encode(project));
   if (response.statusCode == 201) {
     project.id = json.decode(response.body)['id'];
     
     _project.add(project);
     notifyListeners();
   print('sucess');
   }
  else {
    print(response.body);
   throw Exception('Failed to add project');
 }
 }

 void deleteProject(Project project) async {
   final response =
       await http.delete(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/project/api${project.id}/'));
   if (response.statusCode == 204) {
     _project.remove(project);
     notifyListeners();
      print('sucess');
   }
  else {
  
   throw Exception('Failed to load tasks');
 }
 
 }



   fetchProject() async{
    final response = await http
     .get(Uri.parse('http://mostafahamed.pythonanywhere.com/project/api?format=json'));
   if (response.statusCode==200){
     var data = json.decode(response.body)as List;
     _project=data.map<Project>((json) => Project.fromJson(json)).toList();
    
     notifyListeners();
      print('sucess');
   }
  else {
   // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
   // then throw an exception.
   throw Exception('Failed to load projects');
 }
 }
}
```

here i call back the post method with adding data function

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:project/model/project_model.dart';
//import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:project/model/user_Model.dart';
import 'home_page02.dart';

class NewProject extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewProject({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewProject> createState() => _NewProjectState();
}

class _NewProjectState extends State<NewProject> {
 final TextEditingController projectname = TextEditingController();
  //TextEditingController  datelController = TextEditingController();
  //DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
   //DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();

  // Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  //   final DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
  //       context: context,
  //       initialDate: currentDate,
  //       firstDate: DateTime(2015),
  //       lastDate: DateTime(2050));
  //   if (pickedDate != null && pickedDate != currentDate)
  //     setState(() {
  //       currentDate = pickedDate;
  //     });
  //     else print('empty')
  //     ;}
  void onAdd() {
     //final DateTime? textVal = DateTime.parse(datelController.text);
    final String desVal = projectname.text;

    if (/*textVal != null&&*/  desVal.isNotEmpty) {
      final Project project = Project(/*end_date: textVal,*/ project_name: desVal, user: 1,   /*start_date: null,*/ );
      Provider.of<ProjectProvider>(context, listen: false).addProject(project);
      print('$desVal in sucess');
    }
    else{
      print('empty or vaild');
      //print('$textVal in vaild');
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      // App Bar The upper part in the application
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor:const Color(0xff076792),
        title: const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 50.0,
          ),
          // project Name
          child: Text(
            'New Project',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 25.0,
                shadows: [
                  Shadow(
                      color: Color(0xa6A2B6D4),
                      offset: Offset(7,5),
                      blurRadius:20),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
          color:Colors.white,
          size: 30.0,
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0,
                top: 30.0,
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 80.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Creating New Project',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    color: Color(0xff076792),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(43, 24, 43, 15),
              child:  SizedBox(
                height: 45,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: projectname,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Enter project Name", //اليوسر يدخل اسم المشروع
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Color(0xffc9c9c9), /*height: 2.5*/
                    ),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide:
                            BorderSide(width: 2, color: Color(0xFF09679a))),
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // Container(
            //   margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(43, 0, 43, 20),
            //   child: SizedBox(
            //     height: 45,
            //     child: TextField(
            //       controller: datelController,
            //       onTap: () {
            //           showDatePicker(
            //           context: context,
            //           initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            //           firstDate: DateTime.now(),
            //           lastDate: DateTime(2050),
            //         ).then((value) {
            //           datelController.text = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value!);
            //         });
            //       },
            //       decoration: const InputDecoration(
            //         hintText: "End Date",
            //         hintStyle: TextStyle(
            //           fontSize: 20,
            //           color: Color(0xffc9c9c9),
            //         ),
            //         enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            //             borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Color(0xFF09679a))),
            //       ),
            //       keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
            //     ),
            //   ),
            // ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 54,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(75, 0, 75, 0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  onAdd();
                  //_selectDate(context);
                      //Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Create',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: const Color(0xFF09679a),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      // f... flutter buttons!
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, top: 15.0, right: 60.0),
                child: Text(
                  'By Creating This Project You Will Be Admin Of The Project',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              ), //just text
            ),
           // Text(currentDate.toString()),
            // ElevatedButton(
            //   onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
            //   child: Text('Select date'),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**this app made to login users and view projects and add projects like todo app** on the django server i can add project and view projects regstring with admin mail from python backend server .. in this app i can only view projects but cant add new project its my project for graduation so my life depends on this :D
full source code https://github.com/alihassan75/project

Comment: does user with id 1 exists and do they have the necessary permissions to do what you are doing?

Comment: You are passing a null value to the server. Where the value is required please print the values that you are passing and cross check that the required value is passed to the backend.

Comment: user 1 is excited in the data base

Comment: @AlanBosco i think user value null cuz he cant read the id user thats in my mind idk

Comment: i loged in with my admin user whose have id 1  in the app and still cant post data the values he take to post/make new values project_name then the server should response with project_name:"", user:"",id/*ofthe project*/:""

Comment: save that user id somewhere in local database then fetch from that database when required

Comment: so can u give an example pls @AlanBosco

Comment: how to save data locally?

Comment: YES KINDLY pls provide an example as I'm still a beginner @AlanBosco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the data "user" because you are not saving the "user" after login.

> You need to save the user in any local storage. For, the demo purpose I will be saving that on HIVE

1. Import the hive package in pubspec.yaml
   hive: ^2.1.0
2. In the main function(before run app) initialize and open a box "user"

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
await Hive.openBox('User');
```

3. You can push to user box in login function like this.

```
box = Hive.box('User');
int userId = responseJson['user']['id'];
box.put('user_id', userId);
```

4. You can read the user when ever you want like this.

```
 late Box box;
 late int userid;
 box = Hive.box('User');
 super.initState();
 final data = box.get('user_id');
```

5. Now you can pass the data to the http api call.

Thank you

Comment: i will accept your answer as you inspired me to use shared preference ty